# List of abbreviations with glossaries package doesn´t work

Tags: lists, glossaries, acronyms, output

i´m trying to create a list of abbreviations by using the `glossaries` package. The problem is, that i´m not getting the list of the acronyms, no matter what i try, i don´t get an output at all.

My MWE looks like this:

```
   \documentclass[parsikip=full,oneside, 12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes} 
\usepackage{microtype}      
\usepackage{color}                  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,draft = false,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{apacite}
```

The way i used to try to produce the list of abbreviations looks like this:

```
    \usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
    \makeglossaries
     \newacronym{mk}{MK}{Meme-Kommunikatoren\_innen}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage                      
\listoffigures 
\listoftables
\input{einleitung} 
\input{theorie}
\acrshort{mk}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\bibliography{lit_memes} 
\end{document}
```

ideally the list of acronyms would appear after the list of tables, i´d be really happy if there was a line of dots between the abbreviation and the full term, but the most important thing is the list of abbreviations right now.

I also read the overleaf article (https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/glossaries) for the `glossaries` package but i just can´t get it to work. I´m using Latex with TexStudio, it also produces all kinds of files, like `.glo` and `.glsdefs` files, however the `.glo` file doesn´t contain anything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To configure `glossaries` package correctly, you must set proper configuration to allow MakeIndex to sort glossaries appropriately which must include the following

1. An extension of the input file from which MakeIndex get the data of the acronyms in the document, which is usually `.acn`
2. An extension of a file specifying the style you want, which is usually `.bst` file
3. The file which contains the sorted entries, which is usually `.acr`

You must go to 'commands' then 'configuration'. Specify `makeindex %.acn  -s %.ist -o %.acr`

Upon returning the the main window of document, press 'F9' (or go to Tools -> Glossaries). This creates `.acr` file. When you compile again, you should see the list of acronyms

[image]

I added some extra acronyms to demonstrate how `glossaries` automatically sorts entries even when they do not show up in the text (using `\newacronym`) alphabetically.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

% post the following in Commands -> Makeglossaries "makeindex %.acn  -s %.ist -o %.acr"

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{mk}{MK}{Meme-Kommunikatoren\_innen}

\newacronym{SDSCR}{SDSCR}{Site-Dependent Short-Circuit Ratio}

\newacronym{EV}{EV}{Electric Vehicles}

\newacronym{G2V}{G2V}{Grid-to-Vehicle}

\newacronym{H2V}{H2V}{Home-to-Vehicle}

\newacronym{PG}{PG}{Power Grid}

\newacronym{PEV}{PEV}{Plug-in Electric Vehicle}

\begin{document}
    
    \acrshort{mk}
    
    \acrshort{G2V}
    
    \acrshort{SDSCR}
    
    \acrshort{PEV}
    
    \acrshort{H2V}
    
    \acrshort{EV}
    
    \newpage
    
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
    
\end{document}
```